# how to map the failed projection of a Future

Tags: scala, playframework-2.6, silhouette

In the following code, the function is expected to return instance of `Future[Result]` but I am unable to do so. The code queries database, the database returns `Future[User]`. I think I am able to map the success part of the future but not the failure part correctly. Please see the comment at the end of the function.

```
def addUser = silhouette.UserAwareAction.async{ implicit request => {
    val body: AnyContent = request.body
    val jsonBody: Option[JsValue] = body.asJson

//check for message body. It should be json
    jsonBody match {
      case Some(json) => { //got json in message body.
        val readableString: String = Json.prettyPrint(json)
        println(s"received Json ${readableString}")
        val userProfile: Option[UserProfile] = json.asOpt[UserProfile] //check if json conforms with UserProfile structure
        userProfile match {
          case Some(profile) => { //json conforms to UserProfile.
            println(s"received profile ${profile}")

            val loginInfo = LoginInfo(CredentialsProvider.ID, profile.externalProfileDetails.email)
            println(s"checking if the user with the following details exists ${loginInfo}")

            val userFuture: Future[Option[User]] = userRepo.find(loginInfo) // userFuture will eventually contain the result of database query i.e Some(user) or None
            userFuture.map { user:Option[User] => { //Future successful
                case Some(user) => { //duplicate user
                  println("duplicate user" + user)
                  Future  { Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("duplicate user")))   }
                }
                case None => { //unique user
                    Future { Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess("Not duplicate user"))) }
                }
              }
            }

/***This is the part I am unable to code. I suppose the addUser method expect that the last statement (its return value) is Future{....} but it seems that they way I have coded it, it is not the case. If I remove this code and just type Future { Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess("Internal Server Error"))) } then code compiles. But that logic is not correct because then this message will be sent all the time, not when the future fails!***/
            val userFailedFuture:Future[Throwable] = userFuture.failed
            userFailedFuture.map {x=> Future { Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultSuccess("Internal Server Error"))) }}

          }

            //Json doesn't conform to UserProfile
          case None => Future {  Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Invalid profile")))  } /*TODOM - Standardise error messages. Use as constants*/
        }
      }
        //message body is not json. Error.
      case None => Future {  Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError("Invalid Body Type. Need Json"))) }/*TODOM - Standardise error messages. Use as constants*/

      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to wrap your result in future, as you are already evaluating from future value simple this will do:

```
   futureValue.map{value => //RESULT
}
```

And handling errors in Future, it is recommended to use recover with map like:

```
    futureValue.map{value => //RESULT
}.recover{case ex: Exception => //RESULT
}
```

You don't need to wrap your result in Future, if it is already inside a map or recover block. As the final result outside the map and recover of Future will be Future[Result]. So if you wrap another Future it will become Future[Future[Result]].

Comment: Thanks. So I removed `Future` in `map` and `.recover`. I now get the following error `Error:(96, 59) missing parameter type for expanded function
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: play.api.mvc.Result
            userFuture.map { (userOption:Option[User]) => {`

Comment: That is it. This is a `Playframework` application using `Silhouette` security library. As far as I can understand, the `map` is returning `Ok` which is of type `Result`. But I can't understand why the compiler is complaining.

Comment: Got your error, you need to change the code block in your future.map. change [userFuture.map { (userOption:Option[User]) => {]  TO -> [userFuture.map{ case Some(user) => //work;
case None => }]

Comment: worked. So does `.recover` now.Thanks. You are a Genius! Though I don't understand why it worked? In fact, looking at Scala documentation, the example of map is `val g = f map { x: String => x + " is now!" }`. So why I had to remove `userOption:Option[User]`?

Comment: The above error was, you were directly trying to use match case after declaring the variable(i.e either you can do as i did above or if you want to follow your pattern then you will have to do this -> future.map{value:Option[User] => value match { case Some(user) => 
case None => //}})

Comment: I hope this should clear your doubt, don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Agree with answer by @geek94 .
One amendments:

It's not clear what library you are using but in most cases there is no need to call `future.recover` explicitly. Every decent http library (e.g. akka-http) treats failed future as InternalServerError.